# connecting android application with akka remote server

Tags: android, akka

I am building an application with android platform. Will like to design a server side akka application that will provide services in a distributed manner to the android application. Both systems are designed as separate applications. Will it be possible to connect the akka remote server with the android application. Please help me out cos I am new to both akka and android.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but you will suffer.

You must somehow be able to access the class definitions for akka-remote and dependencies (netty, scala) from your android app. This can be problematic, since the sum of dependencies has more than 65536 methods which is Dalviks cap. (That is - your `classes.dex` file inside the apk cannot have more method definitions than 65536).

AFAIK, there's three main approaches:

1. *Split up the dependencies into separate apklibs and make your apk depend on these.*

   - I can't really recommend this since I haven't tried it.
2. *Split up the dependencies into separate classes.dex files that you load programmatically from your app*.

   - Probably doable. Never tried it.
3. *Run proguard before packing your classes.dex*

   - You'll have to battle with proguard to get the config right, and you may get strange runtime failures. My config is posted below.

Once you get akka-remote up and running on your android device you can connect to the server like in the examples in the docs. However, keep in mind that:

- The IP of your Android device may or may not be available at boot time, so you may wan't to keep that part of your akka config dynamic (haven't done this myself).
- The IP of your Android device may not be reachable from the server. So if you get into a state where the server needs to call the client back, it will never succeed.

My proguard.cfg (some lines are not needed - haven't bothered figure out which ones):

```
-dontoptimize
#-optimizationpasses 2
-dontobfuscate
-dontpreverify
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontnote **
-verbose

-keep class com.typesafe.config.Config { *; }
-keep class com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory { *; }
-keep class org.slf4j.Logger { *; }
-keep class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory { *; }

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

#Scala
-dontwarn scala.**

-keepclassmembers class * {
      ** MODULE$;
}

-keep class scala.Option
-keep class scala.Function1
-keep class scala.PartialFunction
#https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5397
-keep class scala.collection.SeqLike {
    public protected *;
}
-keep class scala.Tuple*

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keep class * implements org.xml.sax.EntityResolver

-keepclassmembers class * {
    ** MODULE$;
}

-keepclassmembernames class scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool { *; }

-keepclassmembernames class scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread {
    int base;
    int sp;
    int runState;
}

-keepclassmembernames class scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask {
    int status;
}

-keepclassmembernames class scala.concurrent.forkjoin.LinkedTransferQueue { *; }

#Akka
-dontwarn org.jboss.netty.logging.**
-dontwarn org.osgi.**
-dontwarn javax.servlet.**
#-dontwarn org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.http.**

## Unsafe is there at runtime
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe{
    *;
}

-keep class akka.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage {
    *;
}
-keep class org.javatuples.** { *; }
-keep class org.jboss.**

-dontwarn org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.marshalling.**
-dontwarn org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.**
-dontwarn org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibEncoder
-dontwarn org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.spdy.SpdyHeaderBlockZlibCompressor
-dontwarn org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.http.HttpTunnelingServlet
-dontwarn org.jboss.modules.**
-dontwarn __redirected.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
-dontwarn org.slf4j.MarkerFactory
-dontwarn org.slf4j.MDC
-dontwarn org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLogger
-dontwarn org.slf4j.impl.AndroidLoggerFactory
```

Good luck.

Comment: Using Spray on Android you also may run into the issue described [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22586).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you were thinking of using the Akka remoting protocol, but if it were me, I would consider looking into the excellent HTTP+REST library Spray (http://spray.io/).  I've played around with this library and it is very slick.  It is well integrated with Akka and would allow you to provide REST APIs for your services.  As a bonus, going REST also allows you to have services that will easily integrate with things other than your Android frontend.

I've included a couple of links as a starting point. The Google 2010 I/O talk on writing REST clients for Android apps is especially interesting:

http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/1076

Comment: Any luck with this?  I have been unable to get Spray to work on Android, nor to find any evidence of anyone else doing so.